# Event-driven way of (batch-)removing expired data in Java application

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, batch-processing

In our application, we have a concept called **'overlay'**, which **changes the behaviour for a user account until it expires**. Each user account can have zero or one overlays, which are persisted with the user account in the database.

A user can *activate an overlay* (which requires setting the *expiration time*) and *manually remove* it (if it should be removed before its expiry). Also the overlay's *expiration time can be updated*. When an overlay is removed (manually or due to expiration), an *event is triggered* which results in more logic being invoked (e.g. firing a webhook).

What is now a good way to **automatically remove expired overlays from the database**? The application is built with Grails, so it can use Java frameworks, like Quartz. The application runs on several AWS EC2 instances behind a load balancer. The mechanism need to survive application restarts.

The obvious solution is a **periodic batch job**, that runs every X seconds, scans for all expired overlays, and then deletes them. Downside is that this

- creates peaks in the load (since removing overlays creates events which trigger more behaviour)
- leaves expired overlays in the DB before they are removed

Is there a **more "event-driven" way** so that the overlays are removed right when they expire? We have around 50.000 user accounts.

Comment: Do you want this to be DB-independent, or is it running on a specific DB (e.g. Oracle) whose capabilities can be used?

Comment: It is MySQL and it will not change. But I would prefer the logic of this not to live in the DB (through some triggers or else).

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to check (and possibly delete) upon use - i.e. whenever you're retrieving the possible overlay from the database, check if it's expired and delete it if so.

Technically, you could create a database procedure that will check the overlay existence and expiry, possibly delete expired record and then return the correct result to user. If you hide the table (or column) storing the expiry dates from user (= your application) and only allow access through that procedure, the result will be:

- The expired entries are still in database for some time

  - possibly indefinitely, but if at most 1 overlay per user, it's not too much data hopefully
  - it is there, but the application cannot see them
- From the application's viewpoint, there's no possibility to get expired entries
- No peaks in resources consumption
- Might add some overhead

Comment: That is basically what we are doing right now. Downsides: 1. The expiry-checks are mixed up with other logic (which is not super bad), 2. We trigger more logic upon the removal of an overlay (e.g. firing a web hook, or we also show a graph of when an overlay was active to the user). Thus, the overlays should be removed independent of if they are accessed/used.

Comment: Ad 2. fair point - you should probably add that to the question then as it constrains possible solutions.